# C# Redemption wrapper class not firing events

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-redemption

I've written the following wrapper class for an Outlook Add-in using Redemption:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace PSTAttachRemove_Redemption
{
    class PSTWatch
    {
        private Redemption.RDOPstStore pst;

        public PSTWatch(Redemption.RDOPstStore rPST)
        {
            pst = rPST;
            pst.OnMessageMoved += new Redemption.IRDOStoreEvents_OnMessageMovedEventHandler(pst_OnMessageMoved);
        }

        void pst_OnMessageMoved(string EntryID)
        {
            Debug.Print(EntryID);
        }
    }
}
```

In my main add-in code, I am calling this wrapper using this code:

```
void FileStorePopulation(Redemption.RDOStore store)
{
    switch (store.StoreKind)
    {
        case TxStoreKind.skPstAnsi:
        case TxStoreKind.skPstUnicode:
            PSTWatch p = new PSTWatch(store as RDOPstStore);
            watchedPSTs.Add(store.EntryID, p);
            break;
    }
}
```

where *watchedPSTs* is a global variable.

I can see *watchedPSTs* being populated, but the items never fire when moving a message into a PST.  Ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you initialize RDOSession? Do you call Logon or set RDOSession.MAPIOBJECT to Namespace.MAPIOBJECT from OOM?
is watchedPSTs list declared on the global (class) level?
Do you use multiple threads?

Comment: Global from the main add-in.  I changed my methodology and am only monitoring the items.  More code coming for you on the Redemption Group thread (this is all related to my CopyTo add-in)